# Google Cloud Platform taking a long time to load the app and stalling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, gunicorn, fastapi

I'm using a google cloud instance to deploy a PyTorch model and when I `gcloud app browse` and open the link the app seems to be stalling and taking a very long time to load. I will include my `app.yaml` file because I think it has to do with `gunivorn`. In addition, when I un-comment the `-w 24 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker` I get a worker failed to boot message, i.e. `gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>`. Thanks for the help!

```
runtime: python
env: flex
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3
resources:
  cpu: 12
  memory_gb: 72
  disk_size_gb: 60
instance_class: F4_1G
entrypoint: gunicorn main:app #-w 24 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

Comment: Are you running the gcloud app browse command in a GCE instances or in Cloud shell. Can you try to run the command in Cloud shell and see it it helps?

Comment: I've tried using both and I get the same problem.